# Cannot sync project with gradle files

Tags: android-studio

i cannot sync my project with gradle files.
i have this problem with all projects!

error:
`Gradle sync failed: com.android.ide.common.gradle.model.level2.IdeDependenciesFactory.setRootBuildId(Ljava/lang/String;)Vcom.android.ide.common.gradle.model.level2.IdeDependenciesFactory.setRootBuildId(Ljava/lang/String;)V`

i've tried change my gradle dist to newest version (gradle-4.10.3-all) and i've tried delete gradle caches.

Answer (score 0):

in your classpath use:

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

Now in build.gradle copy this code and make it correct as per your application.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.yourapp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = '1.8'
        targetCompatibility = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2
}
```

Comment: this exists by default under dependencies.

Comment: @AmirHosseinHasanzadeh what version of android studio you're using

Comment: Android Studio 3.2.1

Comment: Try disabling offline work from settings try updating studio to latest version and in spite of that if and if all fails download an offline version of gradle and install it.

Comment: @AmirHosseinHasanzadeh in your build.gradle copy and paste the code which i'm updating in my answer maybe it will solve the problem.